# NumberFormatException in String.Format("%05.2f", 8.00)

Tags: java, string-formatting, jformattedtextfield, propertychangelistener

I'm using italian locale for my program so `Float.parseFloat("8,00")` must function well.
But I have encountered a very bad NFE in the following line:

```
this.cuSurfaceJTextField1.setValue(
    String.format("%05.2f",info.getCuSurface()));
```

I note that the above code used to work well up to some changes I made to the listeners that don't look to be related to this line of the code.(Now I have a propertyChangeListener that updates the model when the value is changed.

```
this.cuSurfaceJTextField1.addPropertyChangeListener("value", 
        new PropertyChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        info.setCuSurface(Float.parseFloat(
                (String)cuSurfaceJTextField1.getValue()));
        updateCuSurface();
    }
});
```

The useful part of the exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "08,00"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1241)
    at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:452)
    at View.bars.QuadrateJPanel$11.propertyChange(QuadrateJPanel.java:348)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(PropertyChangeSupport.java:335)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:328)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:263)
    at java.awt.Component.firePropertyChange(Component.java:8382)
    at javax.swing.JFormattedTextField.setValue(JFormattedTextField.java:799)
    at javax.swing.JFormattedTextField.setValue(JFormattedTextField.java:502)
```

Comment: Parsefloat is not locale specific. 

Related question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233012/convert-string-with-dot-or-comma-to-float-number

Comment: @Simplefish That's right! Maybe that line of my code was never executed before and I thought that it works well! I tested it a simple sample. Isn't there  something that gives me a localized parseFloat? the value that java returns me has , and it isn't a good practice to change it.

Comment: @HotLicks I must convert and format the value because my JFormattedTextField is masked as "##,##". So I need String

Comment: @Johnny NumberFormat and DecimalFormat is probably what you're thinking of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm using italian locale for my program so `Float.parseFloat("8,00")` must function well.

No. `Float.parseFloat` is not locale dependent. So, there are two ways to fix your issue:

- Format like this:

  ```
  String.format(Locale.US, "%05.2f",info.getCuSurface())
  ```
- Replace the comma when you parse:

  ```
  info.setCuSurface(Float.parseFloat(
          ((String) cuSurfaceJTextField1.getValue()).replace(',','.')));
  ```

Comment: That's it man! It works excellent when I used String.format(Local.getDefault(),.... and the first line of my main is Locale.setDefault(Locale.ITALY);

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there may be some confusion over your `Locale`? I've seen this myself - in America and other places numbers are written as "8.00" but in parts of Europe (France was what gave me trouble) it is written as "8,00". Seems like when `String.format()` is called it is in a `Locale` that uses commas... but setting the value on the `JTextField` is automatically parsing the passed-in string with `Float.parseFloat()` which is not sensitive to `Locale` matters - it looks for `.` and that's it.

Comment: Anyway the error is not at that line! and the program doesn't arrive to that line!

Comment: What line? The `String.format()` and `JTextField.setValue()` happen on the same line, the line that gave you the error.

Answer (score 1):

parseFloat doesn't use the default locale, it calls FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(s).floatValue().

Instead use [NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) which will honour the Locale set

```
public class NFE {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.ITALIAN);
        NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance();
        //Float.parseFloat("8,00");
        System.out.println(format.parse("8,00"));

    }
}
```