# Converting string value with comma to Decimal with correct Locale

Tags: java

I am trying to create Double object from decimal string value where comma is floating separator.

Passing locale arguments to vm:

```
-Duser.country=BR
-Duser.language=PT


String value = "500,21";        
Double dob = new Double(value);
```

Getting exception:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "500,21"   at
>   sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1224)
>     at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:475)    at
>   java.lang.Double.(Double.java:567)

Comment: Simply replace the comma with the dot and it will always work ;)

Comment: I know, but I am asking regarding locale change

Comment: The parsing and formatting of Double, Integer, Float, etc. objects are very poor (and old).  They don't support Locales: see Javadoc for Double.valueOf (which I think is what the constructor ends up calling).  So, like Mena says, you must use NumberFormat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that `new Double(value)` does not take into consideration the locale setting.

The implementation ends up calling this method [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/misc/FloatingDecimal.java#FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString%28java.lang.String%29) and it is only looking for ".".

With the locale set as you did you can use this:

```
NumberFormat.getInstance().parse(value).doubleValue()
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233012/convert-string-with-dot-or-comma-to-float-number) is a similar discussion.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with a localized `NumberFormat`:

```
String value = "500,21";
// replace the hard-coded Locale definition with your arguments, or
// Locale.getDefault(), etc.
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("pt", "BR"));
try {
    Double d = nf.parse(value).doubleValue();
    System.out.println(d);
}
catch (ParseException pe) {
    // TODO
}
```

**Output**

```
500.21
```

Comment: Thigh might work, but any reason Double(string) is not working with provided locale?