# Why on client I see that I pass string with comma but on server this string with dot?

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring-mvc, web

I have the following form fragment:

```
<form action="/owner/terminals/edit" method="POST" id="editTerminalForm101">
       ...
       <div class="line">
            <input type="text" id="cost" name="cost" value="5,00">               
            <div class="clear"></div>
       </div>
</form>
```

and the following server side code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/owner/terminals/edit"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String editTerminal(@RequestParam(value = "terminalId") Long terminalId,
            @ModelAttribute TerminalRawDTO terminalDto,
            Principal principal, RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs)
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
                 LOG.trace("cost from client:[{}]", terminalDto.getCost()); // outputs 5.0 (note that dot rather than comma)

}
```

Dto:

```
public class TerminalRawDTO {    
   ....    
    private String cost;    

    public String getCost() {
        return cost;
    }    
    public void setCost(final String cost) {
        this.cost = cost;
    } 
}
```

For me this code works fine but another human says that sometimes in logs he sees cost with dot(expected separator is comma). He sais that it is browser specific behaviour for him. I tried to test in chrome and mozilla - and it works fine for me.

Can you help to understand this strange behaviour ?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your server-side code you are converting the `cost` value from a floating-point number to a String - I suspect that this is where the change from dot to comma occurs. Some float to String conversions are locale aware and some aren't, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233012/convert-string-with-dot-or-comma-to-float-number) for more details.

If someone else sees different results to you it may be that they have different localisation settings on their server.

Comment: **public static long getCentsAmount(String moneyString) throws ParseException {
        DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
        df.setParseBigDecimal(true);
        BigDecimal currencyAmount = null;
        currencyAmount = (BigDecimal) df.parseObject(moneyString);
        BigDecimal currencyAmountCent = currencyAmount.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(100)).setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        return currencyAmountCent.longValue();
    }**

Comment: I use this code to parse string. and according log information I see that here accepts string with dot

Comment: I tried to switch different locales on my os - I cannot reproduce it