# how to take same formate out put 2.5 and 2,5?

Tags: java, number-formatting

Input can be given both way in my software, when I give 2.5 , it return 2.5. but whem I given 2,5 it give me, 2.0 . This is my code ;

```
 public PrescriptionNotationParser()
  {
    final NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance();

    if (numberFormat instanceof DecimalFormat)
    {
      doseValueFormat = (DecimalFormat) numberFormat;
      doseValueFormat.applyPattern("##.########");
      decimalFormatSymbols = doseValueFormat.getDecimalFormatSymbols();
    }
  }

  private double parse(final String valueStr)
  {
   try
    {
      return doseValueFormat.parse(valueStr).doubleValue();
   }
  catch (ParseException e)
  {
    return 0;
   }
}
```

Expect some expertise help to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert String with Dot or Comma to Float Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233012/convert-string-with-dot-or-comma-to-float-number)

Comment: Numbers parsing depends on used locale in JVM. It is different for different locales, e.g. english locale takes numbers with ',' and and chinese takes numbers with '.' delimiter (this is just an example, I don't remember for certain). Can't offer something perfect here, but you can implement a small chain of responsibility which analyses a string for a special symbol (','/'.') and has it's own pattern to parse strings (e.g. DotUnit will returns true if the string contains dot, or just returns false otherwise and gives control to CommaUnit).

Comment: @AndreyIlyunin my system use both Swedish and English env. Swedish use ',' as Decimal point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`2.5` is a float, but `2,5` isn't float format, so `2,5` will only get the previous value `2`.

If you want support `2,5` to `2.5`

```
private double parse(String valueStr)//remove final
  {
   try
    {
      //replace valueStr "," to "."
      return doseValueFormat.parse(valueStr.replace(",", ".")).doubleValue();
   }
  catch (ParseException e)
  {
    return 0;
   }
 }
```

If you want `23,000 .50` to `23000.5`, only remove `,` and space. 
a float `.` only one at most.

```
private double parse(String valueStr)//remove final
  {
   try
    {
      //valueStr remove all "," and " "
      return doseValueFormat.parse(valueStr.replaceAll(",| ", "")).doubleValue();
   }
  catch (ParseException e)
  {
    return 0;
   }
 }
```

Comment: what happen user input , 23,000 .50 this kind of text . ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display your input always in english format (with a point . )
You can use the placeholder %s-String for any primitive type.

```java
float x = 3.15f, y = 1.2345f;

System.out.printf("%.4s and %.5s", x, y);
```

**Output: 3.15 and 1.234**

**%s is always english formatting regardless of localization.**

If you want a **specif local formatting**, you could also do:

```java
import java.util.Locale;

float x = 3.15f, y = 1.2345f;

System.out.printf(Locale.GERMAN, "%.2f and %.4f", x, y);
```

**Output: 3,15 and 1,2345**

And of course you can use an if condition like if Locale.GERMAN then display Locale.GERMAN