# InputMismatchException when reading float via Scanner.nextFloat()

Tags: java, variables

When I use the program with an integer value it works, but when I input a float (such as 47.3) it doesn't. Can you please help me in defining the problem?

**the code:**

```
package ex1;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {

    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        float n;

        System.out.println("enter a number:");

        n = input.nextFloat();

        if (n > 0 && n % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println("the number is positive and even");
        }
        else if (n > 0 && n % 2 != 0) {
            System.out.println("the number is positive and odd");
        }
        else if (n < 0 && n % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println("the number is negative and even");
        }
        else if (n < 0 && n % 2 != 0) {
            System.out.println("the number is negative and odd");
        }
        else if (n == 0) {
            System.out.println("the number is zero");
        }

    }
}
```

**the problem:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextFloat(Scanner.java:2496)
    at ex1.test.main(test.java:14)
```

thanks

Comment: What input are you giving it?

Comment: n = input.nextFloat();

Comment: No I said it works fine with integers... But when I input a float number it shows that error... I don't know why.

Comment: try 47.3 as an input

Comment: It could be you're having a Locale issue, where your code is expecting a comma as the decimal separator.   Try `47,3`  as input.

Comment: You found the problem! Thank you so much @azurefrog

Comment: There's a question here that talks about how to handle floating point input regardless of Locale: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233012/convert-string-with-dot-or-comma-to-float-number

Comment: thanks alot for sharing!

Comment: @Khalil you should answer your own question. Also, edit your title to something that points directly at your problem, such as "InputMismatchException when reading float via Scanner.nextFloat()"

Comment: @MattPutnam I will. I'm a new user here hahaha

Comment: @Khalil No problem! SO is designed to be a repository of good questions with good answers, so it's perfectly okay (and encouraged) to answer your own questions if you figure it out.

Comment: @MattPutnam yess you are right! understanding is the key.

Answer (score 0):

A comma is considered as a decimal separator in Java. So to use a Float input you should replace the '.' by ','