# NumberFormat.parse("3.14") returning 314 when used with German Locale

Tags: java, localization, number-formatting

When I try to read the string "3.14" as a float using German Locale I expect one of two things to happen:

(1) throw an error, because that is not a valid way to write 3.14 in German 
(2) fallback to a more standard decimal notation and read the number as 3.14 because that is what any German would read in that number

But instead I am getting 314.

```java
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;


public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(
            NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMANY).parse("3.14")
        ); // prints 314
    }
}
```

The [oracle-documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) for `parse` states:

> Number    parse(String source) 
> Parses text from the beginning of the given string to produce a number.

Which does not really explain what I am seeing here as it doesn't specify any non-happy path.
What is the javas understanding of a German decimal number, and how can I fail-fast and safely convert Strings to numbers assuming a German decimal notation?

Comment: I think it takes `.` as thousand separator (and so just ignored). Parsing numbers (and dates) is still not yet a solved problem (all or most locale formats just expect formatting in the other direction, so they fails to handle the common formats, but one)

Comment: Are you expecting/desiring 3,14?

Comment: @Jiminion I was expecting the number `3.14f` or an error, Neither is the case, see mine and the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you're facing is because the . is considered the grouping separator in the German locale:

[image]

The previous image is extracted from the DecimalFormat.java class

After that, if the parse finds the grouping character is just ignoring it:

```
} else if (!isExponent && ch == grouping && isGroupingUsed()) {
    if (sawDecimal) {
        break;
    }
    // Ignore grouping characters, if we are using them, but
    // require that they be followed by a digit.  Otherwise
    // we backup and reprocess them.
    backup = position;
}
```

Before you ask, `sawDecimal` is `false` and the backup is initially -1 at the start of the loop and -1 when the next digit 1 is found. So, `backup = position`; is not doing anything.

Comment: Thanks. I began writing my answer before your was there, looks like we found the same stdlib-function as the culprit. I know that "." is the German thousands-separator, sorry that wasn't clear from my question. I would have expected the input string to be invalid because the thousands-separator is not in the thousands-position.

Answer (score 0):

The basic assumption that NumberFormat would validate its input is wrong. A modern dev might expect a validation, especially because the method throws a `ParseException` as a checked exception, but with the magic of open-source I can look at the source and realize I am very wrong and this Java 1.1 code was written with different design principles than I am used to.

The critical code section in the concrete class that we are using here (for one implementation) is in [openjdk > DecimalFormat.java > int subparseNumber](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/1aae980c549741cf5fc5ca51f3c299285bafa49d/src/java.base/share/classes/java/text/DecimalFormat.java#L2436), where the input string gets converted into a "DigitList". The digit-list for "3.14" with a German locale is indeed `[3, 1, 4]` because the thousands-separator is indeed ignored as @GiacomoCatenazzi pointed out in his comment <sup>1</sup>, so subsequent code has to interpret it as 314. Also, when an invalid character is encountered, the parsing just stops, so for example "0x134" -> 0 with no error.

There is more to learn from the source-code: NumberFormat is not threadsafe, you may not reuse the same instance across multiple threads. The modern assumption that a function like `format.parse(input) -> obj` would be trivially safe because input and format are only accessed readonly does not hold - parsing changes internal state of the NumberFormat-instance. You can only reuse the instance after `parse` completes.

---

So how *do* I make a failfast conversion of Strings to numbers in Java?

(1) If you know the target type and the number is in the standard decimal format, this works:

```
Float.valueOf("3,14"); // NumberFormatException
Float.valueOf("3.14"); // 3.14f
```

Note that `NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().parse("3,14")` will return 314 - not an error - so this no-validation-problem is in no way exclusive to the German Locale.

(2) If I have to use German-locale-number-strings for reading numbers, I must check if the input-string matches expectation and *NumberFormat does not provide any way to do that*, nor does there seem to be a satisfying fail-fast/non-gigo answer to this 12-year old question about the problem: [Convert String with Dot or Comma to Float Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233012/convert-string-with-dot-or-comma-to-float-number)

The best idea I have is to validate the input myself and restrict it that way. Here is a solution that is stricter than necessary, banning thousands-separators completely, but for my usecase, this is fine:

```java
if (inputString.contains(".")) {
           // throw
}
return Float.valueOf(inputString.replace(',', '.'));
```

---

<sup>1</sup> You can actually do `format.setGroupingUsed(false)`, and then you can parse "3.14" as a 3 instead of a 314, so it is not entirely true they get fully ignored. But there is no code that uses the grouping-character to judge the correctness of the input String, even though there is `format.setGroupingSize` and getter which controls how many digits should be grouped together.